# Electron: Linking pages using buttons click event

Tags: javascript, button, electron

I have created a button(Connect), when I click it should go to the other page(second.html). It works with localhost, but not with Electron App. What am I doing wrong?

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(() => {
            $( '#buttonConnect').on('click',() =>{
                const inputIp = $('#ip');
            

                if(inputIp.val() !== ""){
                    window.location.href = "observer.html ?ip="+inputIp.val();
                }else{
                    alert("Check Connection Settings!");
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonConnect">Connect</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to communicate with electron from your remote window to tell it which URL to load.

Using [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) is the recommended way of doing that. 
<sub>(a former solution was using [remote](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) which is **deprecated** now)</sub>

In your remote code (your jQuery code from above, in this case):

```js
let { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

$(document).ready(() => {
    $( '#buttonConnect').on('click',() =>{
        const inputIp = $('#ip');     

        if (inputIp.val() !== ""){
            ipcRenderer.send("load-page", `second.html?ip=${inputIp.val()}`);
        } 
        else {
            alert("Check Connection Settings!");
        }
    });
});
```

In your main electron code (probably `app.js`):

```js
let electron = require("electron");
let { BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

// ...

ipcMain.on("load-page", (event, uri) => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ /* ... */ });

    // I don't know your directory structure. 
    // You may have to adapt the following line. 
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/${uri}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, 
// index.js
let { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

$(document).ready(() => {
    $( '#buttonConnect').on('click',() =>{
        const inputIp = $('#ip');     

        if (inputIp.val() !== ""){
            ipcRenderer.send("load-page", "observer.html?ip=${inputIp.val()}");
        } 
        else {
            alert("Check Connection Settings!");
        }
    });
});

//index.html
 <script>
        window.api.loadscript('./index.js');
    </script>

no reaction from Button :(

Comment: @KnAsubi Change `<script>window.api.loadscript('./index.js');</script>` to `<script>require("./index.js");</script>`